# hibernate is not running the inserts and updates at the time of execution

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
@Transactional
public long generateInvoice(...) {
        final InvoiceEntity invoice = new InvoiceEntity(...);

        final InvoiceEntity dbInvoice = invoiceService.save(invoice);

        List<CorrectionEntity> corrections = correctionService.findAllByVendor(...);
        corrections.forEach(correction -> correction.setInvoice(dbInvoice));
        correctionService.saveAll(corrections);

        InvoiceEntity finalDBInvoice = invoiceService.getInvoiceById(dbInvoice.getId()).orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);

        documentService.generateExcel(finalDBInvoice);

        return dbInvoice.getId();
}
```

As you can see I want to set all the corrections for an invoice and then reload them from database to generate the XLSX file.

The problem is that the data is not available in `finalDBInvoice` because, from what I have noticed in the logs, the `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s are executed at the end of the method, probably because of `@Transactional`. When I want to generate the Excel file, the `corrections` field is `null`.

From my point of view, I was expecting this to work properly. With JDBC something like this would've worked because each statement would have been executed at the right time in a single transaction.

```
@Table(name = "invoice")
public class InvoiceEntity {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "futureInvoice", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CorrectionEntity> corrections;
}

@Table(name = "correction")
public class CorrectionEntity extends BaseTimestampedEntity {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "future_invoice_id")
    private InvoiceEntity invoice;
}
```

Comment: Does the invoiceService not have a separate @Transactional annotation that has a different propagation value that might start a new transaction?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: The problem is not with Hibernate. The problem is with your code. You set the invoice on the corrections, but you don't set the corrections on the invoice. So it keeps its default value. It's your responsibility to maintain the coherence between the managed entities.

Comment: @JBNizet does that mean that I have to set each other on each other and save both of them?

Comment: You're already saving both, but saving the corrections is useless, since they are already managed. But yes, you need to maintain both sides of the association.

Comment: @JBNizet I still don't get it. I tried to set the corrections on the invoice and save it and it was not working.

Comment: Edit your question, and post your new code.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.The hibernate commit transaction in the end of methods. you have two choise:
1. Separate save and read data to generate excel in two methods and call them one after another.
2.use method flush after insert or save. like this:

```
//correct
@Transactional
public long generateInvoice(...) {
    final InvoiceEntity invoice = new InvoiceEntity(...);

    final InvoiceEntity dbInvoice = invoiceService.save(invoice);
    invoiceService.flush();

    List<CorrectionEntity> corrections = correctionService.findAllByVendor(...);
    corrections.forEach(correction -> correction.setInvoice(dbInvoice));
    correctionService.saveAll(corrections);

    InvoiceEntity finalDBInvoice = invoiceService.getInvoiceById(dbInvoice.getId()).orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);

    documentService.generateExcel(finalDBInvoice);

    return dbInvoice.getId();
```

}